# Flyway syntax error in one environment and not in another

Tags: linux, continuous-integration, cicd, flyway

we are getting error on below code

"Syntax error near unexpected token ("

#Define an array to store schema names

```
            schema_names=()

            echo "Current Directory: $(pwd)"

            #Find all SQL files and populate the schema_names array

            for script_file in $(find "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/deployment-extract/flyway" -type f -name "*.sql"); do

                #Extract the schema name dynamically from the file path using awk

                myschema=$(echo "$script_file" | awk -F'/deployment-extract/flyway/' '{split($2, a, "/"); print a[1]}')

                if [ -n "$myschema" ]; then

                    schema_names+=("$myschema")

                else

                    echo "Schema name not found in file path: $script_file"

                    exit 1

                fi

            done
```

we try to change our env , its working in one env but not in another.

not sure why its not working

Comment: What language is the code in? Some shell? Looks like bash? [Edit] your question and add a tag for it. Mark the line where the error happens with a comment. If it's a shell script, send it through https://shellcheck.net first. If it's a shell script, how do you call it, with the actual shell or with e.g., `/bin/sh` which may point to different shells on different Unixes / distributions. Compare versions of the program (shell?) you use in the environments. Maybe you use features that the older version does not understand?